# How to get Parameters from a URL on a router.post?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, router

On my web site I stuck in the change password part.

I send an email to the user to change the password, on this link I pass a token on the URL to use is to find the user with findOne.

My problem is the following I was able to get the URL on the router.get but I cannot get it on router.post. I need too get it on router.post because I receive the password from the user on router.post.

Here is my code :

**server.js**

```
    if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    const dotenv = require('dotenv')
    dotenv.config();
}

const express = require('express')
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts')
const passport = require('passport')
const flash = require('express-flash')
const session = require('express-session')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')

const app = express()

require('./passport-config')(passport);

const indexRouter = require('./routes/index')
const registerRouter = require('./routes/register')
const loginRouter = require('./routes/login')
const parentRouter = require('./routes/parent')
const animatorRouter = require('./routes/animator')
const confirmationRouter = require('./routes/confirmation')
const activateRouter = require('./routes/activate')
const cguRouter = require('./routes/cgu')
const confidentialiteRouter = require('./routes/confidentialite')
const lost_passwordRouter = require('./routes/lost_password')
const Change_passwordRouter = require('./routes/change_password')

app.set('view engine','ejs')
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
app.set('layout', 'layouts/layout')

app.use(expressLayouts)
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended : false }))
app.use(flash())
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())


const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}).then(()=>{
    console.log('Successfully connected to the mongoDB Atlas!')
}).catch((error)=>{
    console.log('impossible to connect to the mondoDB Atlas !')
    console.error(error);
});

app.use('/', indexRouter)
app.use('/register', registerRouter)
app.use('/login', loginRouter)
app.use('/animator', animatorRouter)
app.use('/parent', parentRouter)
app.use('/confirmation', confirmationRouter)
app.use('/activate', activateRouter)
app.use('/cgu', cguRouter)
app.use('/confidentialite', confidentialiteRouter)
app.use('/lost_password', lost_passwordRouter)
app.use('/change_password',Change_passwordRouter)

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000)
```

**change_password.js**

```
    const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Users = require('../models/register')

router.get('/:token', async (req, res) =>{
    let {token} = req.params
    console.log(token)
    let user = await Users.findOne({resetPasswordToken: token})
    user.save()
    console.log(user)
    res.render('change_password/change_password')
    res.send(token)
})
    
router.post('/', async (req, res)=>{
    let {token} = req.params
    console.log(token)
    // const user = await Users.findOne({ Users.resetPasswordToken })
    // console.log(user)
    // console.log(user)
    // user.password = req.body.password
    // await user.save()
    })

module.exports = router
```

**change_password.ejs**

```
<form action="/change_password" method="POST">
<div>
    <label for="password">New Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
</div>
<button type="submit">Login</button>
```

**lost_password.js**

```
    const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Users = require('../models/register')
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const flash = require('express-flash')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const secret = require('crypto').randomBytes(64).toString('hex')

router.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.render('lost_password/lost_password', {message : req.flash('success')})
})

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
    user: '',
    pass: ''
    }
});

router.post('/', async (req,res)=>{
    const user = await Users.findOne({email: req.body.email})
    if(!user) {
        return res.status(401).json({
            success: false,
            message: "This email do not exist in our base"
        })
    }
    user.resetPasswordToken = jwt.sign({ email: user.email}, secret, { expiresIn: '1h'})
    user.save()
    req.flash('success', 'An e-mail has been sent to ' + user.email + ' with further instructions.')
    console.log(user.resetPasswordToken)
    const mailOptions = {
        from: '',
        to: user.email,
        subject: 'Localhost activation link',
        text: 'http://localhost:3000/change_password/'+ user.resetPasswordToken,
        html:'<a href="http://localhost:3000/change_password/'+ user.resetPasswordToken+ '">link</a>'
        };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
        }
    });
    res.redirect('/lost_password')
})

module.exports = router
```

**lost_password.ejs**

```
    <h1>Lost Password</h1>
<form action="/lost_password" method="POST">
    <div>
        <label for="email">Indiquez votre email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
<%= message %>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I do not agree with you I feel that everything needed is here to give some clue. I mean there is not a lot of code. The server is quite basic express.

Comment: Please hide the email information and other secrets from your code!

Answer (score 0):

Just change your
`router.post('/')`
with `router.post('/:token')`

Comment: Thank you for your help, ok I tried but It tells me : Cannot POST /change_password I don't know why.

Comment: Can you make changes to your question with updated code.

Comment: I had the same dilema... it works on my machine @Dhaval